# Install R package 'rgdal' and its external dependencies offline on windows

Tags: r, package, installation, offline, rgdal

My work laptop has no internet access and I am trying to download the package rgdal.

I have downloaded rgdal_1.4-8.tar.gz, gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz and proj-6.3.2.tar.gz. I tried intalling them via source separately using:

> install.packages('.../...tar.gz', type='source', repos=NULL)

but it did not work. Here are the error messages

```
ERROR: cannot extract package from 'D:/Users/sn/Documents/R source packages/gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/Users/sn/Documents/R source packages/gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

```
ERROR: cannot extract package from 'D:/Users/sn/Documents/R source packages/proj-6.3.2.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/Users/sn/Documents/R source packages/proj-6.3.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

```
Error in download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/gdal2/archive/v%s.zip",  :
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/rwinlib/gdal2/archive/v2.2.3.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/gdal2/archive/v%s.zip",  :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Execution halted
make: *** [Makevars.win:27: winlibs] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgdal'
* removing 'D:/Users/sn/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rgdal'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/Users/sn/Documents/R source packages/rgdal_1.4-8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What is the error that you are facing?

Comment: Please indicate the error logs-

Comment: Did you already try install_local (devtools) ?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram I have include the errors

Comment: @Jrm_FRL error logs included

Comment: @user12256545 I already have the package 'devtools' installed. What does install_local do?